# How java.exe and javaw.exe are used in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I know the use of *java.exe* and *javaw.exe* in command console, but how are they used in Eclipse?

Comment: You may also find this useful: [Difference between using java.dll and javaw.exe (or java.exe) in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30416414/814702)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Eclipse launcher uses *javaw* internally to launch Eclipse. You can see the settings in *eclipse.ini* file in your installation. This lets you easily identify Eclipse in the list of processes in the task manager instead of seeing another Java process.

When you Run/Debug Java programs inside Eclipse, it defaults to using Java to launch another jvm, but I believe you can set it to use *javaw* if need. Some launchers use *javaw* by default, I think the Tomcat launcher (in WTP) is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please explain a bit what you are trying to do?

If you want to launch a program, using "Run" and "Run as" will do the trick. You can also configure it to use command-line options, environment variables, etc

Comment: no i am not trying it out in eclipse... i used these two in command console... so i am curious to know how these two are used seperately in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse should call java.exe javaw.exe when you click on Run As -> Java Application
You also can select which exe to uses in the run-settings

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Eclipse uses javaw.exe to run; this is the java process that doesn't use a CMD console window.

Java.exe is sometimes launched by Eclipse, to run projects or servers from within the IDE.