# Difference between running Eclipse on jvm.dll and java.exe (or javaw.exe)

Tags: eclipse, windows, jvm

What is the difference between using *jvm.dll* and *java.exe* as the JVM for Eclipse to run on?

---

*DISCLAIMER*
*I have posted this question along with the answer because I find this information useful and want to share this with others.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## How Eclipse is launched when no -vm is specified

OK, just to resolve a confusion: fresh installation of Eclipse on Windows has no *-vm* configuration specified in the *eclipse.ini* file.

Let's see what the official *Equinox Launcher* [documentation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_Launcher#No_-vm_specified) says about situation when no `-vm` is specified (emphasis mine):

> When no `-vm` is specified, the launcher looks for a virtual machine first in a JRE directory in the root of eclipse and then on the search path. If
> Java is found in either location, then we look for a JVM ***shared library*** (*jvm.dll* on Window, *libjvm.so* on *nix platforms) relative to that Java executable.
>
> - If a JVM ***shared library*** is found we load it and use the JNI    invocation API to start the vm
> - **If no JVM shared library is found**, we exec the Java launcher to start the vm in a new process

So as you can see, the *jvm.dll* is the one that is searched for in the first place, and ONLY if it is not found, THEN the Java launcher (i.e. java.exe or javaw.exe) is used.

---

## Difference between using *jvm.dll* and *javaw.exe* (or *java.exe*)

- When using ***jvm.dll*** Eclipse uses the JNI Invocation API to
  start the vm **in the current process**. You will see only ONE process in the task manager:
  *eclipse.exe*
- When using *javaw.exe* (or *java.exe*) Eclipse executes that Java
  Launcher to start the vm **in a new process**. You will see TWO processes in the task manager:

1. *eclipse.exe*
2. *javaw.exe* (or *java.exe* if it was configured)

The *javaw.exe* will be the *sub-process* (child process) of the *eclipse.exe* process.

So the choice is up to you.

---

## Other thoughts

One of the most recommended options to use is to **specify a specific JVM** for Eclipse to run on. Doing this ensures that you are absolutely certain which JVM Eclipse will run in and insulates you from system changes that can alter the "default" JVM for your system. Read more here: [Specifying the JVM](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM)